# Why linux is live bootable and windows is not?

Tags: linux, windows, livecd

I have used different flavors of Linux.Most of them were live bootable i.e, they were able to boot off a USB media / CD and were able to run a live session.But I haven't yet found any Windows OS that is able to do this.

Why Linux is able to do this / windows isn't ? Is there any Windows OS that is able to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has Windows PE, which is what the install media is run from. Essentially a very small, very light Windows OS that is live bootable.

As for why Windows doesn't generally push for live bootable like Linux, it likely has to do with licensing.

That said, aside from PE, [live booting Windows is possible](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/09/22/how-to-run-windows-8-from-a-usb-flash-drive/).

Comment: Windows 8 Enterpise also has `Windows To Go`. As you point out for everyone else Windows PE can fullfill the reminding use cases.

Comment: It is possible to install Windows versions to CD/DVD, but it will throw lots of errors.  Windows installations are not designed to run this way.